# Script en bash y sed para sustitur una cadena

Tags: bash, script, sed, archivo

Tengo un script en bash, donde para leer ficheros, le introduzco por teclado junto a la ejecucción del script el directorio para leer los ficheros y la cadena que quiero que elimine de los ficheros ($1).

Esta variable (el directorio donde debe leer ficheros, la leo con $2)

ahora bien, necesito que en esos ficheros me sustituya justamente el directorio ($1) con sed por un retorno de carro (\n).

ejemplo:

$1 -> /root/Desktop/prueba/

$2 -> /root/Desktop/ficheros_modificados/

introduzco para ejecutarlo:

```
./leer_fich.sh /root/Desktop/prueba/ /root/Desktop/ficheros_modificados/
```

Fichero de ejemplo a.txt que esta en /root/Desktop/ficheros_modificados/ que contiene:

`/root/Desktop/prueba/esto es una prueba /root/Desktop/prueba/no funciona /root/Desktop/prueba/ipconfig /root/Desktop/ficheros_modificados/mask`

Tengo este código que no me funciona:

```
listar_txt=$(sed -i 's/'$1'/\n/g' $2/* )
echo $listar_txt
```

y quiero que el fichero a.txt resulte así:

```
esto es una prueba
no funciona
ipconfig
mask
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

El problema lo tienes por usar "/" como separador en el comando para sed, ya que las cadenas que quieres procesar incluyen ese mismo caracter.
Debes utilizar un separador diferente - por ejemplo "+":

`sed -i 's+${1}+\n+g'`

Además creo que debes corregir otras cosas en el script, pero me parece que tu principal problema era este.